# onScroll event not getting called in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>

div {`border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;`

    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Try the scrollbar in div.</p>

    <div id="xyz">In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.</div>

    <p>Scrolled <span id="demo">0</span> times.</p>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("xyz").onscroll = myFnction;
    var x = 0;
    function myFnction() {

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x += 1;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

i also tried onscroll event inside div tag like  but its also not working.if any one have solution to this please respond.

Comment: Works fine for me in IE11.

Comment: Works for me as well. Here is fiddle for tests http://jsfiddle.net/wdb09zg5/

Answer (score 0):

Is there any typo in css ??

try this css :

```
div {
     border: 1px solid black;
     width: 200px;
     height: 100px;
     overflow: scroll;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nksnk89z/